# Jemos PODAM nesting depth

Tags: java, jemos-podam

Is it possible to set nesting depth when generating objects with [PODAM](https://github.com/mtedone/podam)?

There's a maxDepth setting for recursion but apparently not for general nesting.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stop population after some level unless there is a loop in dependency tree. But why do you need this feature? Could you please describe use case for this. The only problem I could see is possible performance issues, but this requires a lot of classes to form a massive dependency tree without loops.